# Math kernel library applications

Tags: ida

I am looking for a way to simplify functions accelerated by math kernel libraries ...is there any way to make flair signature out of them to understand it better. For instance, I want to get the original data structure or math function for this code (e.g sin or cos or array in math kernel)

For instance:

```
do
      {
        v18 = (__m128i)_mm_cmpneqps(
                         _mm_unpacklo_ps(
                           _mm_unpacklo_ps((__m128)*(_DWORD *)(v17 + 160), (__m128)*(_DWORD *)(v17 + 240)),
                           _mm_unpacklo_ps((__m128)*(_DWORD *)(v17 + 200), (__m128)*(_DWORD *)(v17 + 280))),
                         0LL);
        v16 += 8LL;
        v19 = _mm_sub_epi32(
                0LL,
                (__m128i)_mm_cmpneqps(
                           _mm_unpacklo_ps(
                             _mm_unpacklo_ps((__m128)*(_DWORD *)v17, (__m128)*(_DWORD *)(v17 + 80)),
                             _mm_unpacklo_ps((__m128)*(_DWORD *)(v17 + 40), (__m128)*(_DWORD *)(v17 + 120))),
                           0LL));
        v17 += 320LL;
        v15 = _mm_add_epi32(_mm_add_epi32(v15, v19), _mm_sub_epi32(0LL, v18));
      }
      while ( v16 < v14 );
```

This was created by libmmd.dll 11.1

Comment: What do you mean by simplify !! Be more specific when asking questions, otherwise it will either be closed or voted down ;)

Comment: I mean a very similar structure to what was originally written before compiling using MKL. For instance, you may use sin or cos or eigen function in math kernel  and it gets translated to these types of SSE dependent instructions which are not human readable (at least for me )

Comment: find definition of v17, place cursor on it, press y, enter _DWORD* .This is the only simplification you can do in this specific code.